# Troubleshooting JSONException: End of input at character 0

Tags: java, android, json

I am doing a search on Active.com using their API and currently my search is getting stuck at this error : org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0. I am a newbie,Any help is appreciated.

**MainActivity**

```
      private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(StayActiveActivity.this,"","Please Wait...");

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String result = ActiveHelper.download(params [0]);
                return result;
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("alatta", "Problem making search request");
            }
            return "";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
                m_results = obj.getJSONArray("results");
                if (m_results == null || m_results.length() == 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No Results found for " + m_search_text.getText(), 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else
                    m_search_results.setAdapter(new JSONAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

private class JSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public JSONAdapter(Context c){

    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
    return  m_results.length();
        }

    public Object getItem(int arg0){
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int pos){
        return pos;

    }

    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View tv;
        TextView t;

        if (convertView == null)
            tv = m_inflater.inflate (R.layout.item, parent, false);
        else
            tv = convertView;
        try {
            /* For each entry in the ListView, we need to populate 
             * its text and timestamp */
            t = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.text);
            JSONObject obj = m_results.getJSONObject(pos);

            t.setText (obj.getString("event") + ": " + 
                        obj.getString("text"));

            t = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.created_at);
            t.setText (obj.getString("created_at"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("alatta", e.getMessage());
        }
        return tv;
    }

   }
```

**ActiveHelper**

```
 public class ActiveHelper {

private static final String ACTIVE_SEARCH = "http://api.amp.active.com/search?&v=json&api_key=rm4agnjv6k4m4tvpft95xvbn";
    private static final int HTTP_STATUS_OK = 200;
    private static byte[] buff = new byte[1024];



 public static class SearchException extends Exception {
        public SearchException (String msg)
        {
            super (msg);
        }

        public SearchException (String msg, Throwable thr)
        {
            super (msg, thr);
        }
 }
        protected static synchronized String download (String parm)
                throws SearchException
            {
                String url = ACTIVE_SEARCH+ parm;
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
                    if (status.getStatusCode() != HTTP_STATUS_OK)
                        throw new SearchException("Invalid response from search.active.com" + 
                                status.toString());
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream ist = entity.getContent();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int readCount = 0;
                    while ((readCount = ist.read(buff)) != -1)
                        content.write(buff, 0, readCount);
                    return new String (content.toByteArray());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new SearchException("Problem using the API", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

**StackTrace**

```
06-11 15:01:27.569: E/alatta(7698): Problem making search request
06-11 15:01:27.569: W/System.err(7698): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-11 15:01:27.569: W/System.err(7698):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
06-11 15:01:27.569: W/System.err(7698):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)
06-11 15:01:27.569: W/System.err(7698):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
06-11 15:01:27.569: W/System.err(7698):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
06-11 15:01:27.569: W/System.err(7698):     at my.stayactive.plan.StayActiveActivity$SearchTask.onPostExecute(StayActiveActivity.java:120)
06-11 15:01:27.569: W/System.err(7698):     at my.stayactive.plan.StayActiveActivity$SearchTask.onPostExecute(StayActiveActivity.java:1)
06-11 15:01:27.569: W/System.err(7698):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
06-11 15:01:27.569: W/System.err(7698):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
06-11 15:01:27.579: W/System.err(7698):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
06-11 15:01:27.579: W/System.err(7698):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 15:01:27.579: W/System.err(7698):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
06-11 15:01:27.579: W/System.err(7698):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
06-11 15:01:27.579: W/System.err(7698):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 15:01:27.579: W/System.err(7698):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-11 15:01:27.579: W/System.err(7698):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
06-11 15:01:27.579: W/System.err(7698):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
06-11 15:01:27.579: W/System.err(7698):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your question mentions a `JSONException` but none of the code you've posted actually does any JSON processing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the actual stack trace from the exception. From your description it sounds like the result of your HTTP request is returning an empty string. You might also consider using the EntityUtils.toString method instead of doing the string conversion yourself: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29

Comment: The API specified format:                                       URL: http://api.amp.active.com/search?{queryString params}&api_key={key}
Method: GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onPostExecute(...)` I think you need to use `_results` for the name of the `JSONArray` and not `results`...

```
m_results = obj.getJSONArray("results"); // Change to "_results"
```

Comment: Tried it but still getting the same response.

Comment: @Noble6 : Ah, OK. In your `download` metod try `return new String (content.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");` - the second parameter specifies encoding.

Comment: No luck with it.Wondering if search URL is an issue here, The API specifies the search URL to be http://api.amp.active.com/search?k=marathon&v=json&api_key=rm4agnjv6k4m4tvpft95xvbn Where k=marathon is search parameter.If I try URL+param I get error.

Comment: @Noble6 : The url is fine. I took the url from your `ACTIVE_SEARCH` string and entered it into my browser and got a valid JSON string in the browser window. That's how I knew the array name is `_results`. Not sure what else to suggest other than logging the result string and checking logcat to make sure it isn't being corrupted.

Comment: my result is being returned null

Comment: @Noble6 : OK, so in your `MainActivity` what are you passing to the `AsyncTask` as the `doInBackground(params)` parameter?

Comment: Parameter is what user enters like marathon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting the result back? You can verify by putting a Toast message before you get the `JSONObject`. Generally this error is thrown only when the response is null or blank. Though the API return result when accessed via browser, may be something is preventing it from getting the response in the environment you are testing.